# Set project compiler compliance settings to 1.7 Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-1.7'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm try import project from IDEA to Eclipse Kepler (Ubuntu 13.10, java 7)
meet the this code compatible with java 7,

```
 String action = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.ACTION_KEY);
        switch (action) {
            case Constants.HIDE_PROGRESS:
```

but when I changed it java compiler to 1.7 I meet the following error,

```
 Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

Fix Project Properties set java compiler to 1.6 and I meet first error, it's like a circle.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 cannot switch on `Strings`, you'll need to use `if` and `else` statements if you want to maintain Java 6 compliance.

Comment: actually I want to use Java 7 :)

Answer (score 0):

Just once do .

`Right click your project Go to > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties`

Comment: I do this, but I meet that "Java 6 cannot switch on Strings"

Comment: @user2756073 Update your question with your new issue.

Comment: this is first in my question